# What is the efficient and/or right way to transfer a unique_ptr to another?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

For example

```
class A
{
public:
    setB(unique_ptr<B> b) {???;}
    setB(unique_ptr<B>& b) {???;}
    setB(unique_ptr<B>&& b) {???;}

private:
    unique_ptr<B> mB;
};
```

How to transfer or move (not copy) the arguments content's ownership to the class member?

Comment: The first and `mB = b;`?

Comment: Do you mean the 1st and 3rd use it?

Comment: @chris: In all cases you would need to set the member with `mb = std::move(b);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first and third alternatives are basically equivalent in the particular case of `std::unique_ptr`, and better than the second alternative (which does not allow temporaries).

The first and third alternatives are equivalent in that from the caller point of view she needs an rvalue-reference to construct the argument to the first overload. Conceptually there is potentially an extra copy of `std::unique_ptr` but I doubt that will cause any real instruction in the binary and even if it did, it would be just a pointer copy and setting (2 cpu instructions)

Comment: Does the third need the `std::move`? Do you think using `swap` is fine or better for the 1st and 3rd?

Comment: @user1899020: *Does the third need `std::move`?* Yes, an *rvalue-reference* is an lvalue, so you need to move. *Do you think using swap is fine or better for the 1st and 3rd?* I wouldn't do it, you are conceptually *moving* from the argument to the member. I believe that the code should represent the intention, even though `swap` will get the same result (except that the time of destruction might be postponed if there is any other code in the function.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a situation where #1 or #3 would work, but the other wouldn't.  I'm coming up pretty blank: you can't get a pointer to a constructor.  I guess inheriting from it, then use inherited constructors with signature?  Double user conversions cannot happen, so I cannot make a function that only returns `T&&`, and even if I did it could be used to construct the `T`...

Comment: @Yakk: If you have a `std::unique_ptr<>&&`, then that can be used to construct a value in call cases, note that this does not require an additional conversion. In general you should not use rvalue-references for arguments *unless* you need to discriminate between an lvalue and an rvalue, so I would be inclined to use the first overload. But for a move only type, where the only alternative are *rvalue-references*, the set of inputs that match one or the other overload are exactly the same.